# Change the least significant bit (LSB) in java

Tags: java

I am trying to change the LSB of a numerical value, say 50 which LSB is 0 because 50 % 2 is 0 (remainder operator) to a value of 1. Thus change the LSB from 0 to 1 in this case.
The code is below:

```
//Get the LSB from 50 using the modulas operator
lsb = 50 % 2;

//if the character equals 1
//and the least significant bit is 0, add 1
if(binaryValue == '1' && lsb ==0)
{
     //This clearly does not work.
     //How do I assign the altered LSB (1) to the value of 50?
     50 = lsb + 1;
}
```

I am having problems inside the if statement, where I am tying to assign the altered LSB, which in this case is 1 to the value of 50. This is not the full code, thus all values are different.
Thanks

Comment: I hope that's pseudocode

Comment: It is just a rough example of what I am trying to do

Comment: Do you always want to change it? (`x ^ 1`) Always make it 1? (`x | 1`) Make it 1 inside that `if` with the fewest "weird operators"? (`x + 1`) Or something else? Maybe, make it equal to some value? (`x & -2 | newlsb`)

Comment: OK so if x ^ 1 = 1. How do I make is equal to 0?
Thanks

Comment: Make the LSB 0: `x ^ (x&1)`, make the LSB 1: `x | 1`, flip the LSB: `x  ^ 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [xor operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) `^` can be used to flip the value of a single bit. For example

```
int value = 4;
value = value ^ 1;
System.out.println(value);
```

Will output 5 since the least significant bit was changed to one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure what you mean by xor operation, and masking bits in that matter?

Comment: Then you should probably google _"xor java"_ or something like that. It's quite simple. However, since you have numerical values you could also go with `++x`? (`x` is 50 here). But that's not a nice one-liner

Comment: @DouglasGrealis I updated my answer to be more verbose

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Makes sense. Now if it was a value of 3. How can I use the XOR operator to change it to 0?

Comment: `a ^ b` means: flip every bit in `a` if the corresponding bit in `b` is 1. Thus `3 ^ 1` will change the least significant bit in 3 to 0 so the expression will be 2

Comment: @DouglasGrealis can you explain the actual function that you're trying to implement? Making 3 -> 0 does not match with the question.

Answer (score 3):

XOR in java:

```
System.out.println(50 ^ 1);
```